# Loop through table rows inside placeholder in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have placeholder and inside it I have panel. Inside panel I have table and inside table I have radiobuttonlist in each row.How can I loop through each table row and fins radiobuttonlist selected item?.Please help.

Code is as follow:

```
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(panel);
    Table table = new Table();            
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
    var rd1 = new RadioButtonList();
    TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();
    TableRow tRow2 = new TableRow();
    TableCell tCell1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tCell2 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tCell3 = new TableCell();
    tRow1.Cells.Add(tCell1);
    tRow2.Cells.Add(tCell2);
    tCell2.Controls.Add(rd1);
    table.Rows.Add(tRow1);
    table.Rows.Add(tRow2);                    
    panel.Controls.Add(table);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try code like following.

```
    foreach(Control ctrl in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        if(ctrl is Panel)
        {
            foreach(Control ctrlPnl in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if(ctrlPnl is Table)
                {
                   foreach(TableRow row in ((Table)ctrlPnl).Rows)
                    {
                        foreach(TableCell cel in row.Cells)
                        {
                            foreach(Control ctrlCell in cel.Controls)
                            {
                                if(ctrlCell is RadioButtonList)
                                {
                                    //Do your stuff here
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(GetRadioButtonList("RadioButtonList1"));
        }
        private RadioButtonList GetRadioButtonList(string ControlID)
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
            rbl.Items.AddRange(
                new ListItem[] {
                            new ListItem("Item 1", "1"),
                            new ListItem("Item 2", "2"),
                            new ListItem("Item 3", "3"),
                            new ListItem("Item 4", "4"),
                            new ListItem("Item 5", "5"),
                            new ListItem("Item 6", "6"),
                            new ListItem("Item 7", "7"),
                            new ListItem("Item 8", "8"),
                            new ListItem("Item 9", "9"),
                            new ListItem("Item 10", "10")
                    });
            rbl.ID = ControlID;
            return rbl;
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
            Response.Write(rbl.SelectedValue);

        }

    }


Use  ->PlaceHolder1.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
```